# How to connect remote machine by remote user name?

Tags: ssh, remote-access

How to connect a correct remote Linux by using Remote Linux user name because my IP keeps a change.

Note: my remote PC and my PC always connect the same wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the SSH command line client is basically

```
ssh remoteuser@host
```

where `host` is the hostname or IP address of the remote host.

What do you mean by changing IP address? If both,  server and client are capable of zeroconf, you can always use the zeroconf hostname (usually with domain `local`) as host name.